# invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,265'

Tags: python

I'm trying to use the numbers from a list and i got the ValueError saying 'invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,265'.
I understand that this error is raised when I put in a string representation of sth other than integer into the int() function.
Therefore, as you can see from line 3~7, I tried to strip any empty space and remove the comma in all of my numbers in the list. 
However, I'm still getting the same error.
Can anyone tell me what's causing the error and how I can fix it?

```
    n = len(pairs)
    density_sum = 0
    for i in pairs:
        i[0].strip()
        i[1].strip()
        i[0].replace(',','')
        i[1].replace(',','')
    for i in pairs:
        density_sum += int(i[0])
    average_density = density_sum / n
    population_sum = 0
    for i in pairs:
        population_sum += int(i[1])
    average_population = population_sum / n
    numerator = 0
    for i in pairs:
        numerator += (int(i[0])-average_density)*(int(i[1])-average_population)
    denominator = 0
    import math
    for i in pairs:
        denominator += (math.sqrt((int(i[0])-average_density)**2))*(math.sqrt((int(i[1])-average_population)**2))
    coefficient = numerator/denominator
    print(coefficient)
```

9     density_sum += int(i[0])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,265'

Comment: You **must** provide a [mcve]. Please provide code and error messages *as formatted text in the question itself*. Do not post screenshots

Comment: Actually, I can't see. Post your code, not an image of it.

Comment: @PaulSung, you have to assign value to the variable after you replace or strip. That is : ```i[0] = i[0].replace(',','')```

Comment: Sorry, guys. I'm new to StackOverflow. I just thought screenshots would be more comfortable, but i won't use them from now on.

Answer (score 1):

Error is with your string which containing the number, `int()` does not accept `,`, Try:

```
num = int("".join(string.split(",")))
```

The `split` function will split it into two stings at the `,` and `.join()` will combine them into a single string.